# get number of lines outputted by ls when output is to tty (not to pipe/file)

Tags: shell, zsh

In a zsh function I want to get the number of lines that the output of ls has (when formatted in a table in the terminal).

`ls | wc -l` obviously does not work, as the output of ls is different when piped, so this would just count the number of files.

Comment: [Be careful when parsing the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Please add a [mre]. Sounds like a [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate? [How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/118235)

Comment: If you solve a problem yourself, use the "Add an Answer" button to add the answer _as an answer_ so it can be voted on / commented on / edited / moderated separate from the question itself. [Answers should **never** be edited into questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404545) -- doing so privileges the OP's self-answer above all others; the only approved way for the author of a question to choose one answer to privilege is with the "accepted answer" checkbox.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you, this link helped a lot

Comment: You could use `ls -C`: _Force multi-column output; this is the default when output is to a terminal_.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by installing `expect` (for `unbuffer`) and using

```
alias unbuffer='unbuffer '
unbuffer ls --color=never | wc -l
```

The alias with a trailing space for `unbuffer` causes `ls` to be expanded in the second line if `ls` is an alias, as flags such as `--group-directories-first` or `-x` could change the number of lines outputted by `ls`